# If the professor is teaching in a way that I don't like, what should I do?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, undergraduate

It is a required course. I major in stat/math. The professor only writes down his notes on the blackboard, never explains intuitions of the theorems, never starts with easy/simple examples, never explains why the material is important etc.

Comment: Do your best to get through the class. Don't take that professor in the future if there is someone else teaching the same class. What kind of answer are you looking for here?

Comment: I'm confused by the tags.  Is this a graduate or undergraduate class?

Comment: First step: Ask questions in class.  "What is the intuition behind this theorem?"  "What is a simple example of this?"

Comment: Perhaps less so in math than physics, I find that appeals to, or requests for, 'intuition' are fraught with difficulty because intuition is a personal thing - what is 'intuitive' to me is often different than what is intuitive to somebody else. (This crops up violently in physics when students hit quantum mechanics - their Newtonian intuition is no longer valid and they can't stand it). But, interactions in class, in office hours, or with other students are the obvious paths towards clarification of problems.

Comment: Majority rules; how fellow students perceive the lectures?

Comment: @NateEldredge This is a good answer.

Comment: why is my question downvoted????????? Cant understand..

Comment: "This question has been flagged as: off-topic: Questions about problems facing undergraduate students are off-topic unless they can also apply to graduate or post-graduate academicians as described in What topics can I ask about here?"

Comment: Please do not deface your question. See [this help page](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account) for instruction how to delete your account.

Answer (score 2):

In their own training, few professors have taken classes in pedagogy or didactics. That means they learn how to "teach" by doing it, and some of them do so quite badly. So you need to stop the professor after class, and - nicely! - ask if he/she couldn't help you out by providing more simple/easy examples next class.  See if that works. If it does, move on to the next issue bothering you: the importance of the material. And so forth.  Try to help your professor to become a better teacher without making him/her defensive!  I've taught (including statistics) at colleges and universities for 30 years, and I know there's a lot of lousy teaching - and touchy egos - out there...

Comment: Besides for lack of training, there is also the fact that in many departments, as long as your teaching is acceptable, there is little to no external incentive to invest time and energy into improving its quality (not including the intrinsic desire to be effective in the things that you do).